# Lightweight two-way communication between python script and chrome extension

Tags: python, json, google-chrome-extension, comet, reverse-ajax

I want to run a lightweight python script that will communicate with a chrome extension running on the same machine, with the ability to push updates to the chrome extension's background page.

I like the look of bottle.py for the lightweight web-server with easy json communication, but I haven't found any information on how you would do reverse ajax communication without using something like twisted or gevents.

How could I do this in a lightweight manner? I don't need any concurrency, just a single connection.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you will be running a python web server so your extension should do XHR requests to localhost:port?

Comment: Websocket shouldn't be that hard in Python